# iOS5 - Twitter API

Tags: twitter, ios5

I want to use Twitter API which is available in iOS5. And I'm successfully posting to twitter as well. But my fear is that, the deployment target for my iphone is 4.2 and so will the app work perfectly with iOS 4.2 devices?
(I don't have iOS 4.2 device to test that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a weak library link and double-check the classes exist before you use them.

Comment: Yes, that is is the solution to run the app on older devices. But I'll not be able to post to twitter as the framework is not there. is there any solution for this... or do I've to use the framework provided by Twitter?

Comment: Twitter has its own framework? That's new to me :-) If you want to accept older versions of iOS, you'll have to use a different library. I think `MGTwitterEngine` is pretty popular.

Comment: Tom van der Woerdt, When using MGTwitterEngine, its accepting my credentials. but not my client's credentials. (I'm sure that password and username are correct). Has anything changed in twitter enginer. Can you refer me to library of that URL please.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that changed.

Comment: @Satyamsvv I am experiencing the same issue when trying to authorize an app while using MGTwitterEngine.  When using my credentials all is good, outside of that the authorize app view continues to display.  Any luck?  I prefer to use the new Twitter framework but I will have to use MGT on older devices.

Comment: @tg2007, no i don't know any solution for this. previously it was working well. these days it became problematic. may be twitter guys has changed their way of authentication or something else so that iOS5 twitter framework will become popular by using it.

Comment: @Satamsvv if you find a fix please share your findings?  I've lost several days of work trying to find the fix. When I find the fix I'll comment here.